¿Cómo puedo usar transition manejando el estado con React?
<div className={`my-cart ${myCartVisible ? 'cart-active' : ''}`} id='my-cart'>
</div>

Tengo un div de este estilo, que cuando se presiona X boton, se setea myCartVisible a true y se procede a re-renderizar mostrando el contenido del carrito de compras (no incluí el contenido porque me parece innecesario, la funcionalidad funciona bien). Mi CSS es el siguiente:
.my-cart {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  right: -100%;
  z-index: 25;
  padding: 24px 32px;
  width: 20%;
  transition: right 0.5s ease; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.cart-active{
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: all 0.9s;
}

El problema es que la transición de entrada y salida no se hacen, queda muy robusto y feo y no tengo ni idea cómo animarlo, parece que se ignora el transition all 0.9s;.
Capaz alguien podía ayudarme.
Si la pregunta está mal formulada o necesitan más datos, háganmelo saber por favor.

Prueba manejando solamente la transformacion en la segunda etiqueta
.my-cart {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 25;
  padding: 24px 32px;
  width: 20%;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.cart-active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}


